# Android app and library dependencies clash

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

my app uses these dependencies

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

when i imported seek arc library it uses different dependencies

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
  compile project(':SeekArc_library')
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What's exactly the problem? Is there any error thrown? If not, how do you face the problem?

Comment: The top level applications library dependency will override the lower level library dependency . You don't need to override explicitly. Refer to Android build documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the standard gradle build tooling and Android Studio.

Below is the recommended solution for issues of clashing dependencies. Eg say you have declared an explicit dependency on `com.google.guava` version `X` but some other dependency is bringing its own internal dependency on `com.google.guava` version `X-1`.

Add the following after your `dependencies` clause in the `build.gradle` file.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

For details see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html

Note: there is another approach where you may selectively exclude certain dependency from each `compile` clause but it is not recommended since it doesn't scale well. For completeness I'll include it here but I do not recommend it. Using the same made-up example as above

```
compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: 'X')
compile(group: 'com.some.other.dependency', name: 'foo', version: 'bar')
{
    // exclude transitive dependency since we want to depend on version `X` declared above
    exclude(group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5')
}
```

Comment: It's also possible for library dependencies to conflict with classes included in the Android standard library.  For example, any library that transitively pulls in `org.json:json` requires an exclusion.

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried,   configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-jdk5'
}  and got error,     No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Comment: pls make sure that the dependency you are choosing to import explicitly does have the correct version

Answer (score 1):

My App and newly added Library dependencies were in conflict.  I changed app compiled & build sdk to api 23 and added "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'". Now problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The top level applications library dependency will override the lower level library dependency . You don't need to override explicitly. Refer to Android build documentation

Comment: didn't think that was true as i've had issues with that in the past. cold you pls link the doc you are referring to, perhaps i'm misunderstanding your point. thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the dependancies of the library you are using you can

```
compile 'yourLibraryName'{
   exclude module: 'appcompat-v7' 
   exclude module: 'appcompat-v7' 
 }
```

Make sure you provide your own version though, otherwise you'll get runtime errors